# password confusion in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have logged into postgresql server using

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Then I also created a database from within /usr/local/bin directory using the command.

```
createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres testdb
```

When prompted for password, I entered the PostgreSQL admin user password (that I had changed from 'postgres' to 'upendra').

When I do

```
\l
```

in the postgres prompt, I get the following output
[image]

When I connect to testdb from within the postgres prompt, I am not required to enter the password. the connection is instantaneous.

However, when I try to connect to this database from the terminal using

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 postgres testdb
```

I am required to enter password. Why is it so?Moreover, no matter what password I type it always says that authentication failed. what's the catch?

[image]

Also, why does the prompt say password authentication failed for user "testdb". From what I have understood, testdb is the name of the database and not the name of the user. The user  name is postgres.

Answer (score 4):

First, to answer the question you asked about the behavior of this command:

```
 psql -h localhost -p 5432 postgres testdb
```

> Also, why does the prompt say password authentication failed for user "testdb". From what I have understood, testdb is the name of the database and not the name of the user. The user name is postgres.

Because you have given two trailing options to this `psql` command: `postgres` and `testdb`. Since neither the `-d` nor `-U` option were given, `psql` assumes the database name should be the first argument and the username should be the second argument, per the [documented Synopsis](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) of the `psql` command.

Second, to answer your other question:

> When I connect to testdb from within the postgres prompt, I am not required to enter the password. ... However, when I try to connect to this database from the terminal using [... `psql`, and getting a password prompt ... ]

`psql` has some logic by which it determines whether it is safe to keep and reuse the password you entered initially, see the logic about `keep_password` in [command.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/f721e94b5f360391fc3ffe183bf697a0441e9184/src/bin/psql/command.c#L1771). Presumably when you are able to use the `\c` meta-command to reconnect from within an existing `psql` session, `psql` is preserving your initial password and reusing it -- either that, or your pg_hba.conf rules allow a connection without a password with the given user/database, e.g. a [trust or ident](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) rule.